# -bash: mysqldump: command not found MAC OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, mamp, mysql

I want to export and import a `.sql` file from MySQL server from to my machine with a command line:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump -P 3306 -h server  -u login  -p passwd  database  > db_backup.sql
```

But I get this error:

> -bash: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump: No such file or directory

Comment: Well... Have you installed `mysqldump`? Wherefrom did you get ‘`/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump`’?

Comment: Locate `mysqldump` in `$PATH` using `which`:

    which mysqldump

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It work well now, I just changed:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump
```

by:

```
/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/mysqldump
```

Answer (score 3):

XAMPP includes all of the MySQL binaries:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysqldump
```